# Python Beautifulsoup retrieving json

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm trying to retrieve the 'inStockQty' json key/value pair using beautifulsoup but am having trouble.

Here's my code so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://direct.asda.com/george/men/shoes/black-leather-lace-up-oxford-shoes/GEM830406,default,pd.html?cgid=D2M1G10C13"
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/602.2.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0.1 Safari/602.2.14'
    headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent,
                   'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'}
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html5lib")
    script = soup.select_one('script:contains("window.priceAvailabilityJSON")')
```

How do I then find 'inStockQty'? I thought about trying to parse all the JSON, but i don't know how to strip out all the HTML crap.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://direct.asda.com/george/men/shoes/black-leather-lace-up-oxford-shoes/GEM830406,default,pd.html?cgid=D2M1G10C13"
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/602.2.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0.1 Safari/602.2.14'
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent,
           'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'}
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html5lib")

script = soup.find(id='main-content').find('script').string
data = script.split('window.priceAvailabilityJSON = ')[1].split(';\nlet product')[0]

json_data = json.loads(data)

# Output
for product in json_data['productAvailability'].values():
    print(product['availability']['inStockQty'])
```

Comment: getting this:

  File "C:\Users\sandhu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\sandhu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\sandhu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 319 column 21 (char 7713)

Comment: I am on Linux and I am unable to reproduce your problem. Сan you provide, variable data output?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/e4QxhtZi

that is the dump of 'data' variable. is it because, if you look at the end, for some reason it is missing end brackets?

Comment: if i switch to anaconda (using spyder instead of pycharm) same issue

Comment: I'm updating answer. Try this. I will wait for your result

Comment: Hey Alex this works, many thanks! any ideas why it worked on linux and not windows? Also are you available for freelance work? Ta

Comment: The problem is not Linux related. The fact is that the promotions variable is null for me, but you don't. There is no time for freelancing now, I am working on one project

Answer (score 0):

**Try Selenium for that job**

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
URL = 'https://direct.asda.com/george/men/shoes/black-leather-lace-up-oxford-shoes/GEM830406,default,pd.html?cgid=D2M1G10C13'

driver.get(URL)

driver.implicitly_wait(5) # wait until content is loaded
```

Call the variable and you can access it´s content:

```
jsonData = driver.execute_script('return priceAvailabilityJSON')
print(jsonData.get('productAvailability'))
driver.close()
```

**Output**

```
{'G006386138': {'availability': {'backorderable': False, 'inStockQty': 6, 'instock': True, 'isBackorder': False, 'level': 'instock'}, 'badgesInformation': {'backorderInformation': {'backorderMessage': '', 'backorderableMessage': '', 'displayBackorderMessage': False}, 'displayLowStockBadge': False}, 'price': {'available': True, 'list': {'currency': 'EUR', 'decimalPrice': '27.0', 'formatted': '€ 27.00', 'value': 27}, 'vat': 16}}, 'G006386139': {'availability': {'backorderable': False, 'inStockQty': 2, 'instock': True, 'isBackorder': False, 'level': 'instock'}, 'badgesInformation': {'backorderInformation': {'backorderMessage': '', 'backorderableMessage': '', 'displayBackorderMessage': False}, 'displayLowStockBadge': False}, 'price': {'available': True, 'list': {'currency': 'EUR', 'decimalPrice': '27.0', 'formatted': '€ 27.00', 'value': 27}, 'vat': 16}}, 'G006386140': {'availability': {'backorderable': False, 'inStockQty': 9, 'instock': True, 'isBackorder': False, 'level': 'instock'}, 'badgesInformation': {'backorderInformation': {'backorderMessage': '', 'backorderableMessage': '', 'displayBackorderMessage': False}, 'displayLowStockBadge': False}, 'price': {'available': True, 'list': {'currency': 'EUR', 'decimalPrice': '27.0', 'formatted': '€ 27.00', 'value': 27}, 'vat': 16}}, 'G006386141': {'availability': {'backorderable': False, 'inStockQty': 5, 'instock': True, 'isBackorder': False, 'level': 'instock'}, 'badgesInformation': {'backorderInformation': {'backorderMessage': '', 'backorderableMessage': '', 'displayBackorderMessage': False}, 'displayLowStockBadge': False}, 'price': {'available': True, 'list': {'currency': 'EUR', 'decimalPrice': '27.0', 'formatted': '€ 27.00', 'value': 27}, 'vat': 16}}, 'G006386142': {'availability': {'backorderable': False, 'inStockQty': 2, 'instock': True, 'isBackorder': False, 'level': 'instock'}, 'badgesInformation': {'backorderInformation': {'backorderMessage': '', 'backorderableMessage': '', 'displayBackorderMessage': False}, 'displayLowStockBadge': False}, 'price': {'available': True, 'list': {'currency': 'EUR', 'decimalPrice': '27.0', 'formatted': '€ 27.00', 'value': 27}, 'vat': 16}}, 'G006386143': {'availability': {'backorderable': False, 'inStockQty': 28, 'instock': True, 'isBackorder': False, 'level': 'instock'}, 'badgesInformation': {'backorderInformation': {'backorderMessage': '', 'backorderableMessage': '', 'displayBackorderMessage': False}, 'displayLowStockBadge': False}, 'price': {'available': True, 'list': {'currency': 'EUR', 'decimalPrice': '27.0', 'formatted': '€ 27.00', 'value': 27}, 'vat': 16}}, 'G006386144': {'availability': {'backorderable': False, 'inStockQty': 7, 'instock': True, 'isBackorder': False, 'level': 'instock'}, 'badgesInformation': {'backorderInformation': {'backorderMessage': '', 'backorderableMessage': '', 'displayBackorderMessage': False}, 'displayLowStockBadge': False}, 'price': {'available': True, 'list': {'currency': 'EUR', 'decimalPrice': '27.0', 'formatted': '€ 27.00', 'value': 27}, 'vat': 16}}}
```

Comment: this works, many thanks but wanted to avoid selenium as it is so slow!